# Selecting specific columns Symfony 2 / Doctrine

Tags: php, sql, doctrine

I'm a Ruby on Rails programmer, but I have decided to start learning Symfony framework for PHP. And I've got a problem with Doctrine:

There's a model of user:

```
id | username | profession | password
```

In a database. I want to create a method that will:

```
SELECT DISTINCT profession FROM user;
```

So I wrote a code like this:

```
$connection = Doctrine_Manager::connection();
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT profession FROM user';
$statement = $connection->execute($query);
$this->professions = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But it's not working properly - it only retrieves the first one not all of the professions (should be 6).

Could you help me please? Is there any easier way to retrieve a single specific field from the table?

Answer (score 0):

Fetch fetches the next column, use fetchAll if you want all at once.

```
$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Or if you want to youse fetch and process one by one (if you don't want to store them in an array),

```
while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['profession'];
}
```